# Wrong directory of the bat file?

Tags: izpack

I am trying to create a installer with IzPack. I am trying to execute a batch file before the installation.

> install.xml

```
<izpack:installation version="5.0" 
                     xmlns:izpack="http://izpack.org/schema/installation" 
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://izpack.org/schema/installation http://izpack.org/schema/5.0/izpack-installation-5.0.xsd">


    <guiprefs width="640" height="480" resizable="yes"/>
     <variables>
         <variable name="DesktopShortcutCheckboxEnabled" value="true"/>
    </variables>

    <locale>
        <langpack iso3="eng"/>
    </locale>

    <resources>
        <res id="ProcessPanel.Spec.xml" src="ProcessPanel.Spec.xml"/>
        <res id="shortcutSpec.xml" src="shortcutSpec.xml"/>
        <res id="LicencePanel.licence" src="License.txt"/>
        <res id="InfoPanel.info" src="Readme.txt"/>
    </resources>

    <panels>
        <panel classname="HelloPanel"/>
        <panel classname="ProcessPanel"/>
        <panel classname="LicencePanel"/>
        <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
        <panel classname="PacksPanel"/>
        <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
        <panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
        <panel classname="FinishPanel"/>
    </panels>

    <packs>
        <pack name="Base" required="yes">
            <description>The base files</description>
            <file src="Readme.txt" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="License.txt" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="phone.ico" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <fileset dir="lib" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH\lib">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </pack>
    </packs>

    <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll"/>
    <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper.dll" stage="both">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </native>
</izpack:installation>
```

> ProcessPanel.Spec.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<processing>                   
     <job name="doxyz">
         <os family="windows" />
         <executefile name="$INSTALL_PATH/scripts/mytest.bat">
             <arg>doit</arg><arg>$variable</arg>
         </executefile>
     </job>            
     <onFail previous="true" next="false" />
     <onSuccess previous="false" next="true" />
</processing>
```

At the compile time, I don't get any error! But when I am executing the install.jar and when I open the ProcessPanel I am getting the following error:
[image]

I used the:

> izpack-dist-5.0.6

to generate the installer and my java version is:

> java version "1.8.0_66" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>
> (build 1.8.0_66-b18) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call this an expected behaviour.

The file `$INSTALL_PATH/scripts/mytest.bat` cannot be found because it isn't probably preinstalled due to the activation order of the panels. *ProcessPanel* is shown before *InstallPanel,* but *InstallPanel* is the one installing the file. Problems of this kind the compiler does NOT complain about, you must care about them on your own. It is more or less a problem of the logic introduced by the installer description, not of IzPack.

Comment: I move the ProcessPanel after the InstallPanel, add the mytest.bat as file of packs and it works! It is possible to shown the ProcessPanel before the InstallPanel and run some batch files ?

Comment: It is. You must just ensure the file is there, for example by an "exists" condition on that file. You can use this condition to show the panel itself or just do some actions. This might be useful for updates of your software and can be used for auto-recognition of updates in favor of installations from scratch.